# Remove daily duplicates from MySQL DB based on two columns in a certain period of days

Tags: mysql, duplicates, distinct

This has been bugging me since 2 days and I can't get my head around it.

I have a MySQL table with the following structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE `sales` ( 
    `id` Int( 255 ) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    `created` DateTime NOT NULL,
    `user` VarChar( 100 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `client` VarChar( 100 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `status` VarChar( 100 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `unique_id` UNIQUE( `id` ) )
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

INSERT INTO `sales` ( `client`, `created`, `status`, `user`) 
VALUES 
( 'Google', '2019-05-06 00:00:00', 'active', 'john' ),
( 'Apple', '2019-05-06 00:00:00', 'active', 'john' ),
( 'Amazon', '2019-05-06 00:00:00', 'inactive', 'david' ),
( 'Apple', '2019-05-06 00:00:00', 'active', 'john' ),
( 'Amazon', '2019-05-07 00:00:00', 'active', 'john' ),
( 'Google', '2019-05-07 00:00:00', 'active', 'david' ),
( 'Apple', '2019-05-07 00:00:00', 'active', 'john' ),
( 'Amazon', '2019-05-07 00:00:00', 'inactive', 'david' ),
( 'Apple', '2019-05-07 00:00:00', 'active', 'john' );
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

A user can only have one client per day, but sometimes the app is sending multiple submissions due to a bug we had over the last few months, so what I want to do is eliminate the manual work I do to clean up the data (export results to excel and clean  by running a query that ignores these duplicates (not delete them).

Returning to my sample data:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+--------+----------+
| id | created             | user  | client | status   |
+----+---------------------+-------+--------+----------+
|  1 | 2019-05-06 00:00:00 | john  | Google | active   |
|  2 | 2019-05-06 00:00:00 | john  | Apple  | active   |
|  3 | 2019-05-06 00:00:00 | david | Amazon | inactive |
|  4 | 2019-05-06 00:00:00 | john  | Apple  | active   |
|  5 | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 | john  | Amazon | active   |
|  6 | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 | david | Google | active   |
|  7 | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 | john  | Apple  | active   |
|  8 | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 | david | Amazon | inactive |
|  9 | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 | john  | Apple  | active   |
+----+---------------------+-------+--------+----------+
```

Expected results after running the query should be:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+--------+----------+
| id | created             | user  | client | status   |
+----+---------------------+-------+--------+----------+
|  1 | 2019-05-06 00:00:00 | john  | Google | active   |
|  2 | 2019-05-06 00:00:00 | john  | Apple  | active   |
|  3 | 2019-05-06 00:00:00 | david | Amazon | inactive |
|  5 | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 | john  | Amazon | active   |
|  6 | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 | david | Google | active   |
|  7 | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 | john  | Apple  | active   |
|  8 | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 | david | Amazon | inactive |
+----+---------------------+-------+--------+----------+
```

The logic: 
In the example above we remove two duplicate records based on day not month and not year.

What makes a duplicate record:
A duplicate record is where two records on the same day have the same value for "client", "user" and "status".

In the example, John, on 05-07-2019 has Amazon as a client twice, but each has a different status, so we don't remove any of the records. But he also has Apple as a client twice but both statuses are Active, that means it's a duplicate so we remove one of them.

Not sure if I made it clear or not, but my last attempt would be to say that simply, daily, we remove the records that have the same values in client, status and user, if any of these three is not identical then it's not a duplicate so we keep both records.

Any help would be appreciated cause this is driving me crazy!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you already have a query to do what you want? if you have then look up 'events' and you can schedule it to run on the server directly.

Comment: No I don't, I'm struggling writing the query, and I don't need an event to do that since this will not delete any records, so I'll use the query to display the records and ignore the duplications.

Comment: PLease share dummy data and expected result data.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I added an example, I hope it's clearer now. Thanks!

Comment: @Sayem I just added a couple of dummy rows with expected results. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just follow the advice provided?

Comment: @Strawberry trying to get my head around sqlfiddle to do that.

Comment: @Strawberry umm not sure I got what you mean.

The row with id 4 was removed because it has the same date, client, status and user as  the row with id 2

The row with id 9 was removed because it has the same client, status, user and date as the row with id 7

The row with id 8 was NOT removed because everything is identical to row number 5 except the status. 

Please note that everything is depending on the date, a user can only have one client on a single day, but he can have the same client the next day. John can have Google and Apple on the same day, but can't have Apple twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've figured out how to construct CREATE and INSERT statements, a query like this should suffice:

```
SELECT MIN(id)id
     , client
     , status
     , user
     , created 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY client
     , status
     , user
     , created 
 ORDER 
    BY id;
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if you tried to offend me with the Create and Insert comment, but anyway.
This worked I guess! so thank you, I'll give it a try on the live dataset I have. 

One quick question though, does changing "created" in GROUP BY to DATE(created) assures that only the day / month / year are taken into consideration or it doesn't matter? cause I also have minutes and seconds set in the datetime field.

Comment: Here's an SQLFiddle link, I think:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4bdc5/1

Comment: You said you were struggling with the process of constructing CREATE and INSERT statements - a struggle evidenced by your failure to provide any (until now); so I guess it's up to you to choose how you feel about that.